# Why does the same .mov flicker on VLC on one Windows laptop, but not on another?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Today, I used IObit Driver Booster to update drivers on Lenovo Y700 Touch-15ISK and IdeaPad Gaming 3 laptops.

Then I went on iCloud.com, and downloaded the same MOV to both laptops.

Finally, I downloaded VLC Media Player on both laptops, and opened my MOV with it.

On the Gaming 3 that runs Windows 11 version 23H2, VLC played this MOV normally.

You can see the glass bottles + brown box + hard wood floor + blue and red stripes.

[image]

But on the Y700 that runs Windows 10 Home version 22H2, VLC played just the audio normally. VLC failed to play the video! The video flitters, flutters, and lags.

[image]

[image]

##### Why does this happen? What shall I do to fix it? To watch the MOV normally on the Y700?

Comment: You should not use  IObit Driver Booster

Comment: "_flitters, flutters, and lags_" ... can you provide a better definition, possibly even a video of it? Any details on the media you're trying to play would be helpful (i.e: total/audio/video bitrates, color depth, codecs, etc...), as would CPU usage during playback. Have you rebooted since installing the new drivers? Did this video file play correctly beforehand?

Comment: @Gantendo Why not? I don't got time downloading each driver singly! I need bulk fast download!

Comment: @Attie Done. "Have you rebooted since installing the new drivers?" **Yes.** "Did this video file play correctly beforehand?" Yes, on iPhone. But today is my first time watching .mov on VLC player.

Comment: @user1147844 Because it causes far more problems than it solves.

Comment: I'm not interested in wether the file plays correctly on another device (you've already stated that it does)... but have you successfully played this file on the physical Y700 laptop that is having issues? A HEVC, 10-bit, 4k video is not trivial to decode, and it's _very_ possbile that the 6th gen Mobile i7 is not up to this task - as the artifacts in the screenshot suggests.

Comment: You've got plenty of time to do things the way they'll work best. IObit may give you some convenience, but it doesn't take that much time, and certainly less than you've spent posting this question, to go through the list of drivers on the Lenovo support site and download and install them. Also, I'd wager Lenovo offers a utility that'll do this too, without the complications of a 3rd party utility.

Comment: @Attie "but have you successfully played this file on the physical Y700 laptop that is having issues? " **No. Never,**

Comment: @music2myear What are the downsides to IObit Driver Booster then, besides consuming some MB?  What problems does IObit Driver Booster beget that makes it unworthy?

Comment: I am suspicious of any 3rd party driver utility: too many malicious products in this category. Secondly, even a "good" product in this space will be at a disadvantage to OEM products regarding drivers it is aware of and the timeliness of it being able to find and present those. Finally, I don't really even like the OEM utilities because finding and installing drivers is super simple for most brands (including Lenovo) and being able to run these myself gives me better control and awareness of the process without taking all that much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lenovo Y700 certainly has specifications (e.g., Intel Core i7, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M, 16 GB RAM) to be *capable* of playing a *good* MOV file without issue, **depending on frame rate and resolution**. You need to do some research and editing of the question to get a useful answer.

- What is the frame rate and resolution of that MOV video?
- Was the PC able to play it without issue *before* using that third-party tool to change drivers? *If so*, do you have a **disk image** to restore the functionality lost from that "update"?
- What are the current versions of *Display adapter* drivers as shown in [Device Manager](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/find-missing-drivers-hidden-components-device-manager/)? Have you [let Lenovo scan your PC and update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-y-series-laptops/y700-15isk/downloads) appropriately?
- What other processes are running, using reosurces that might be needed for video playback? Check CPU, GPU RAM and I/O usage in *Task Manager*?
  [image: Resource Usage in Task Manager]

With information you've given, the issue could be a misconfigured PC, bad hardware, or even malware running in the background, such as a crypto miner or DDoS server.